# Rails - How to set 1 scss file for 1 view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I can't figure out how make certain .scss files work with certain views.  I removed the *= require_tree . from the application.css.scss but I'm not sure where to go from there.  The stylesheet_link_tag doesn't seem to recognize .scss files.  What tag can I use to import .scss files to views?

I also tried creating a different controller for the different view but after I removed the require_tree the controller doesn't use the .scss file that was automatically generated with it.

Comment: What do you mean `stylesheet_link_tag` doesn't recognize `.scss` files? Can you post some code? It should work, so I assume that there is an issue in your view code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important piece you are probably missing is that Sprockets won't serve any asset, mainly the css and js need to be declared in your asset manifest. Quoting the docs:

> If you have other manifests or individual stylesheets and JavaScript files to include, you can add them to the precompile array in config/initializers/assets.rb:

```
      Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ['admin.js', 'admin.css', 'swfObject.js']
```

Use the expected resulting name (with `.css` extension) and not the source file (with the `.scss` extension).

Comment: Thanks.  I was confused by this when reading about it and tried to add it using a .scss extension.  My css file is working now but I'm having the original problem of the css being applied to every view in my application.  I'm using the stylesheet_link_tag in the one view only.

Answer (score 2):

In `application.css` remove `*= require_tree`.

In application.html add:

```
<head>
  <%= yield :stylesheets %>
</head>
```

And on every page render:

```
<% content_for :stylesheets do %>
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag "your file" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I got this working but the css is still being applied to every view in my app.  I only added the stylesheet_link_tag to the one view.  And I did remove the require_tree tag in the application.css.scss.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Adding the yield to the application.html.erb was causing a problem.  The css from the one page was being included on other pages as well which was what I wanted to avoid.  This only happened when I navigated from one page to another though..  Maybe it had something to do with how styles were being cached in the system?  Not sure..  Is all I had to do though was add the stylesheet_link_tag to the page I wanted the different css on.

Comment: css files should be included in the head section.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to organize your assets based on controller.
Rails guide has a [section about it](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#controller-specific-assets).

According to it you can create `app/assets/stylesheets/projects.css.scss` file for your `ProjectsController` and include it like this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] %>
```

> When doing this, ensure you are not using the `require_tree` directive, as that will result in your assets being included more than once.

Action based stylesheets can be created similarly:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "#{params[:controller]}/#{params[:action]}" %>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had already read this part but was still a little confused.

Answer (score 0):

if the scss file is in the root of the asset folder then

add line to your view file

```
=stylesheet_link_tag 'your_scss_file_name'
```

in \config\initializers\assets.rb

add this line

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile + =% w (your_scss_file_name.css)
```